http post request returning error 422 in laravel
I have my Request like this:
class RegisterRequest extends Request
{
    public function rules()
    {
        $rules = [
            'role' => [
                'required',
                'string',
                'exists:sys_roles,slug',
            ],
            'name' => [
                // 'required_without_all:first_name,last_name',
                'string',
                'min:2',
            ],
            'first_name' => [
                'sometimes',
                'string',
                'min:2',
            ],
            'last_name' => [
                'sometimes',
                'string',
                'max:128',
            ],
            'email' => [
                'email',
                // 'unique:sys_users,email',
            ],
            'phone_number' => [
                'sometimes',
                'string',
                'max:32',
            ],
            'password' => [
                'sometimes',
                'min:6',
                'confirmed',
            ],
            'roles.*' => [
                'sometimes',
                'exists:sys_roles,id',
            ],
            'profile' => [
                'sometimes',
                'nullable',
                'array',
            ],
            'document' => [
                'required',
                'string'
            ],
            'address' => [
                'required',
                'array'
            ],
        ];

        /**
         * The username rules can valy accordinly with the user type
         */
        switch ($this->input('role', Role::ADMIN)) {
            case Role::USER:
                $document_rule = \Illuminate\Validation\Rule::unique('sys_users', 'document')->where('status', true);
                array_push($rules['document'], $document_rule);

                $email_rule = \Illuminate\Validation\Rule::unique('sys_users', 'email')->where('status', true);
                array_push($rules['email'], $email_rule);

                break;
            default:
            case Role::ADMIN:
                throw new \UnexpectedValueException(trans('auth.wrong_role'));
        }

        return $rules;
    }

    public function withValidator($v)
    {
        // Adds the correct document validation Rule according to the profile entity_type
        $v->sometimes('document', new \App\Rules\Cpf, function ($input) {
            return !empty($input->document) && $input->profile['entity_type'] === User::PRIVATE_ENTITY;
        });

        $v->sometimes('document', new \App\Rules\Cnpj, function ($input) {
            return !empty($input->document) && $input->profile['entity_type'] === User::LEGAL_ENTITY;
        });
    }

    /**
     * Performs the validation on Resolving (after we change the password to a hash to
     * improve security and save directly on the DB)
     */
    public function validate()
    {
        parent::validate();

        if ($this->filled('password')) {
            $hasher = Sentinel::getHasher();

            $this->merge(['password' => $hasher->hash($this->input('password'))]);
        }
    }
}


And I'm sending the following JSON
{
   "address":{
      "zipcode":"14056-741",
      "address":"Rua Antônia Pimentel da Silva",
      "neighborhood":"Jardim Doutor Paulo Gomes Romeo",
      "number":"555",
      "complement":"",
      "state":"SP",
      "city":"Ribeirao Preto"
   },
   "name":"Tiago Ferezin",
   "email":"tiagoferezin@gmail.com",
   "emailConfirmation":"tiagoferezin@gmail.com",
   "entity_type":"1",
   "document":"325.157.142-55",
   "date_of_birth":"17/06/1985",
   "phone_number":"(99) 99999-9999",
   "phone_number_alt":"(99) 99999-9999",
   "password":"njskeennjje",
   "password_confirmation":"njskeennjje",
   "accept_to_receive_emails":0,
   "terms":true
}

But the request returns error 422 with the following response
{
    "errors": {
        "email": [
            "validation.unique"
        ],
        "document": [
            "validation.unique"
        ]
    }
}

What could be happening and what is the best way to fix this error?
One of the attempts I made was to change the email and the document, hoping to pass validation and thus proceed with the request, but the error persisted.
